# Tuckey URL Rewrite - Remove .html Extensions

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, wildcard, http-redirect, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have look all over the web and can't seem to figure this one out.  I am using the Tuckey rewrite engine.  I have read the manual and reviewed the examples without help.

I want to remove ".html" extensions from the URL, while preserving parameters if there are any.

Here is what I have thus far (non-working):

```
<rule>
    <note>Example: http://hostname/sample/loginhelp?cid=2 is masked from http://hostname/sample/loginhelp.html?cid=2</note>
    <from>^(.*)\?(.*)$</from> 
    <to>$1.html?$2</to>
</rule>
<outbound-rule>
    <note>Example: http://hostname/sample/loginhelp.html?cid=2 is redirected to http://hostname/sample/loginhelp?cid=2</note>
    <from>^(.*)(\.html)(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">$1$2</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

Neither the rule or outbound-rule seem to work in any scenario.  I know the Tuckey is working since I can get other rules to work, just not this one.  Also, I am using the Seam stack although I don't think it matters.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [wildcard matching engine](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/#wildcard) to simplify this:

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <from>*.html?*</from>
    <to>$1?$2</to>
</rule>
```